# Troubleshooting unexpected search results

Tags: search

It appears that there's at least one folder in one of our crawled network shares that's not getting indexed properly, as evidenced by searching for unique words known to be in PDF documents in that folder and not getting the documents back in the search results.  Documents in this folder are showing up in the crawl log as being successfully crawled, either with a "Crawled" or "Not modified" status.  There are no errors or warnings in the Windows event log, and none that I can find in the SharePoint trace logs.  Of the 42 PDF files in this folder, all are less than 5MB in size and most are less than 1MB.

Can anyone offer some tips on troubleshooting this issue?

**Update:** It looks like SharePoint *is* indexing the title metadata for these PDFs, just not the content.  There is text content in the PDFs -- Adobe Reader's Find command works fine within a given document.  What could be causing the content not to be indexed?

Answer (score 3):

Do you have the PDF iFilter installed? Indexing doesn't look inside PDFs natively; you must have the iFilter installed.

Comment: Yes, we've got the Adobe iFilter installed.

Comment: Darn. I was hoping it was something easy. ;+)

Comment: Where are the iFilters installed?  They need to be on the index server, but I've seen people install them on the SQL Servers and WFEs by mistake.

Comment: We've only got one server, and that's where the iFilter is installed.

Answer (score 1):

Did you also configure the Adobe iFilter as [described](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2293357) by Microsoft? Finally, you need to restart the OSearch14 service.